# jquery ajax call from asp.net mvc app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am trying to call an action from jQuery. The action should return true or false,
and based on the return value I will do something.

I have the following code.

```
 $("#payment").click(function (e) {
       if($("#deliverytime").attr("disabled")){
            //something here...   
        }
        else
        {
            var postcode=$('#Postcode').val();
            var restId='<%:ViewBag.RestaurantId %>';
            var URL = "/Restaurant/DoesRestaurantDeliver?restid="+restId+"&&postcode="+postcode;

            $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: URL
             }).done(function(msg) {
                        if(msg==true){
                             $('#commonMessage').html(msg);
                             $('#commonMessage').delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(4000).slideUp(400);
                             return false;
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#commonMessage').html(msg);
                             $('#commonMessage').delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(4000).slideUp(400);
                             return false;
                        }
            }); 



        }
    });
```

The code is not working. It says `'msg' is not defined`. Is this not the way I should do this using jQuery-ajax? What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT:

Controller action

```
public JsonResult DoesRestaurantDeliver(Int32 restid, string postcode)
    {

        if (rest.getDeliveryPriceForPostcode(restid, postcode) == null)
        {
            return Json(Boolean.FalseString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
            return Json(Boolean.TrueString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

### Modified function

```
var postcode = $('#DeliveryInfo_Postcode').val();
            var restId = '<%:ViewBag.RestaurantId %>';
            var URL = "/Restaurant/DoesRestaurantDeliver?restid=" + restId + "&&postcode=" + postcode;
            $.ajax({
                url: URL,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                data: "{}",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!data.hasError) {
                        $('#commonMessage').html(data);

                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

### EDIT -2

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#checkout").click(function (e) {
        getDeliveryInfo();
    });
});
function getDeliveryInfo() {
    var URL ="/Restaurant/DoesRestaurantDeliver/6/2259"
    $.get(URL, function (data) {
        alert(data.isValid);
    });
}
</script>
<%using (Html.BeginForm())
 { %>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="checkout"/>
<%} %>
```

The above code does not work. But If i put the 'checkout' button out side of the form like below, it works.

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm())
 { %>

<%} %>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="checkout"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your **ajax call like below**.

I feel your ajax call having problems on `.done(function(msg) {}` area.

Try to set  `success: function (data) {}` like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var companyName = $("#companyname");

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Company/GetName",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: "{}",
            success: function (data) {
                if (!data.hasError) {
                    companyName.html(data.companyName);
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

**EDIT**

**Action method** should looks like below (This is a sample.Adjust it according to your situation)

```
 [HttpGet]
 public JsonResult GetName(string term)
        {
            var result = Repository.GetName(term);
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**EDIT 2**

I would use **Anonymous object (isValid)** (remember that **JSON is a key/value pairs**):

**Action Method**

```
   [HttpGet]
   public JsonResult DoesRestaurantDeliver(Int32 restid, string postcode)
    {
       if (rest.getDeliveryPriceForPostcode(restid, postcode) == null)
        {
            return Json(new { isValid = false},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
            return Json(new { isValid = true },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**And then inside the ajax method:**

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data.isValid) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3**

Just **change your button type** as below.(since you're not sending any values from form)

```
<input type="button" name="submit" id="checkout"/>
```

Comment: now it says data is not defined. From the controller do I have to return jsonresult? i am returning 'Content(Boolean.Truestring)'..can that cause the error?

Comment: @kandroid yes.need to return json result like i have mentioned in Edit area.

Comment: i think i am doing some silly mistake somewhere around. I tried to debug in Firebug, when it goes to 'sucess:function(data)',it does not go into the function, on the other hand if I try to watch data, it says data is not defined.

Comment: @kandroid Can you put your Action method also ? and check whether inside a fire bug, your parameters are filling with correct values.If those values are not filling correctly then It will not go to the action method due to routing issue.Update your new ajax method also.

Comment: it is hitting my controller action. i have tested it

Comment: @kandroid can you update your latest ajax method and action method both ?

Comment: @kandroid I have updated.Follow your action method and ajax call like  EDIT 2 .

Comment: Hi Sampath. I found out the problem. The action method and the script works perfectly. But the problem is, if I put the submit button inside the html.beginform(), it does not work. but if I put the button outside of the form, it works. what shall I do now? do I need to use ajax form?? is there any way I can use normal form?

Comment: Hi. thanks. If I use button type=button inside the form, it works.But basically in the real scenario, i am using button type 'image' and i am sending lots of values.

Comment: @kandroid Then you can send all the values through jquery without using 'submit' button type is the one solution.B'cos you cannot use both for single button.i.e. Jason result and submit form data.